# Recursive regular expression

Tags: regex

If there is a text like `${placeholder1.${placeholder2}}`, is it possible to have a regular expression to match the text recursively like `${placeholder1.${placeholder2}}` `${placeholder2}`

Comment: Yes, it is possible with Python PyPi regex module, .NET regex, PCRE, PCRE2, Onigmo (Ruby), Boost. Even Lua patterns have recursion support. What is your regex flavor?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm trying in golang.

Comment: No, that is not possible in Golang. Unless you use a PCRE library port.

Answer (score 0):

No, not using a standard regular expression. This is why it is strongly advised not to use a regex to parse HTML. Perl, PCRE and Ruby support an extended form that will instruct the regex to return to the beginning of the pattern and reevaluate the match. See [Regular Expression Recursion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) for more.

In the general case, I'd write a quick parser to handle this use case using a library like [PegJS](https://github.com/pegjs/pegjs).

Comment: There is no standard regular expression. Each regex flavor is different, and some support recursion, some support balanced groups, some do not support these things.

Comment: Hm, I think IEEE POSIX would disagree with you. ;) See https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html

Comment: See [.NET regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3d%28%5c%24%7b%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b%7c%28%3f%3co%3e%7b%29%7c%28%3f%3c-o%3e%7d%29%29*%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%29%7d%29%29&i=%24%7bplaceholder1.%24%7bplaceholder2%7d%7d) demo and [this PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0b8VGf/2/). Your answer is wrong if you say it is not possible as it is possible with regex.

Comment: @RobRaisch I'm trying in golang.